# How to data display before one hrs from start time and hide after one hrs for end time laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to display button or link before one hrs from start time and hide after one hrs from end time in Laravel blade.

I have using Laravel 5.5.

I try:

```
$ptime = date('h:i a',strtotime('-1 hour',strtotime($scheduleGroupWorkout->schedule_start_at)));
$ctime = date('h:i a', strtotime($scheduleGroupWorkout->schedule_start_at));
$cendtime = date('h:i a', strtotime($scheduleGroupWorkout->schedule_end_at));
$eendtime = date('h:i a',strtotime('+1 hour',strtotime($scheduleGroupWorkout->schedule_end_at)));
```

Laravel Blade

```
@if(strtotime($ctime) < strtotime($ptime) && strtotime($eendtime) < strtotime($cendtime))
 <div class="schedule-time-btn">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Join</a>
 </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) class

Comment: is $scheduleGroupWorkout->schedule_start_at a data from eloquent model?

Comment: I suggest that use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Few points you should have to follow :

1. Use Carbon instead of php functions.
2. Best option to load a button is AJAX. No check at the time of page load.
3. Add button in DOM using AJAX by checking current time in between start and end time.
4. Use Blad you ajax controller method to load button
5. By using Ajax no one can temper you button's url, also add UUID to button url so if anyone copy your button, will not use next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon:

```
@if(Carbon::parse($ctime)->lt(Carbon::parse(ptime)) && Carbon::parse($eendtime)->lt(Carbon::parse(cendtime)))

 <div class="schedule-time-btn">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Join</a>
 </div>
@endif
```

If you retrieve data from a model you can add schedule_start_at into models $dates array:

in your model :

```
$dates = ['schedule_start_at','schedule_end_at'];
```

Then laravel will parse date with carbon automatically.

Comment: Don't you think in this case if load page before 2 hrs. Then how it will check that button should be shown or not?

Comment: Updated code :
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($ctime)->lt(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($ptime)) && \Carbon\Carbon::parse($eendtime)->lt(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($cendtime)))

 <div class="schedule-time-btn">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Join</a>
 </div>
@endif